# Memory Management of QTableWidget Items

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, dynamic-memory-allocation

If I add a new QTableWidgetItem to a QTableWidget, do I have to free the memory myself or is it automatically handled. For example:

```
ui->table->setVerticalHeaderItem(0,new QTableWidgetItem(tr("Table Item")));
```

How is the dynamically created QTableWidgetItem handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QTableWidget` takes ownership of the `QTableWidgetItem`. You do not need to delete it.

Comment: What if I were to create a new one when I set a new item in a cell? Does the memory allocated for the previous item get freed?

Comment: @sj755: Yes. Everything is taken care of automatically.